# GET file:///C:/Users/Diego/Documents/Jquery/Jogo%20da%20Velha/o.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com mum problema para resolver no meu codigo onde está aparecendo o seguinte erro :ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND o que pode ser ? estou tentando criar o jogo da velha

```js
var vez = 'o';

function atualizarPlacar(){
    if (vez == 'o'){
        $('.placar img').attr('src', 'o.png');
    }else{
        $('.placar img').attr('src', 'x.png');
    }
}


$(function(){

    atualizarPlacar();

    $('.area').bind('click', function(){
        if($(this).find('img').length == 0 ){
            if(vez == 'o'){
                $(this).html('<img src="o.png" border="0" height="50" />');
                $(this).attr('data-marcado', 'o');
                vez = 'o';
            }else {
                $(this).html('<img src="x.png" border="0" height="50" />');
                $(this).attr('data-marcado', 'x');
                vez= 'x';
            }

            atualizarPlacar();
        }
    });

})
```

```css
 .area {
            width: 80px;
            height: 65px;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top:15px;
        }

        .placar {
            width: 252px;
            height: 80px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body> 
    <div class="placar">
        É a vez de:<br/>        
        <img src="" border="0" height="50" />
    </div>

    <div class="area a1" data-marcado=""></div>
    <div class="area a2" data-marcado=""></div>
    <div class="area a3" data-marcado=""></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="area b1" data-marcado=""></div>
    <div class="area b2" data-marcado=""></div>
    <div class="area b3" data-marcado=""></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="area c1" data-marcado=""></div>
    <div class="area c2" data-marcado=""></div>
    <div class="area c3" data-marcado=""></div>


    
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde se encontram as imagens o.png e x.png?

Comment: Ele esta buscando a imagem o.png e x.png na pasta /Jquery/JogoDaVelha/. Provavelmente o caminho está errado. Você deve alterar para o caminho certo na funcao atualizarPlacar. Caso nao consiga, posta um print da sua estrutura do projeto por favor.